# How can i Wrap a list of Widgets?

Tags: flutter

[image: i have the problem at the buttom] I have this but when i show on the screen, it shows everything in vertical no wrap. and i need it to show like a row everything. i am creating a list of widgets first with all the information that i need for presenting the information with a wrap widget but went i take the list it shows all the information but no wraping.

```
Widget _calcularPrecios(int i, double valor) {
      double trimestral = valor *3;
      double semestral = trimestral *2;
      double anual = semestral *2;
      double contado = anual-anual*0.12;
      if(i==1) {
        return Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: 5,
              height: 50,
              color: Color(0xFF1BB394),
            ),
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0xFFE0F7FA)
              ),
              width: 120,
              height: 50,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Mensual', style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                    Text('\$'+valor.toStringAsFixed(2), style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500))
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        );
      }else if(i==2) {
        return Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: 5,
              height: 50,
              color: Color(0xFF1BB394),
            ),
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0xFFE0F7FA)
              ),
              width: 120,
              height: 50,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Trimestral', style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                    Text('\$'+trimestral.toStringAsFixed(2), style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500))
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        );
      }else if(i==3) {
        return Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: 5,
              height: 50,
              color: Color(0xFF1BB394),
            ),
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0xFFE0F7FA)
              ),
              width: 120,
              height: 50,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Semestral', style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                    Text('\$'+semestral.toStringAsFixed(2), style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500))
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        );
      }else if(i==4) {
        return Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: 5,
              height: 50,
              color: Color(0xFF1BB394),
            ),
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0xFFE0F7FA)
              ),
              width: 120,
              height: 50,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Anual', style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                    Text('\$'+anual.toStringAsFixed(2), style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500))
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        );
      }else if(i==5) {
        return Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: 5,
              height: 50,
              color: Color(0xFF1BB394),
            ),
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0xFFE0F7FA)
              ),
              width: 120,
              height: 50,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Contado', style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                    Text('\$'+contado.toStringAsFixed(2), style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500))
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        );
      }
    }



    List <Widget> _calcular(double valor){
      List<Widget> temporal =[];
      for(var i = 1; i<6;i++){
        temporal.add(_calcularPrecios(i,valor));
      }
      return temporal;
    }

(_calcular(valor).isNotEmpty)? Wrap(
                        children: _calcular(valor),
                      ): Center(child: Text('Presione boton calcular')),
```

Comment: Do you need the clip view type of widget ?

Comment: you need add more information(like your output screen) code snippets is not enough

Comment: You can refer this solution   https://stackoverflow.com/a/61248116/3946958

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem was that all the widgets in the list takes the size of the screen width
so all the rows in the list i put in a SizedBox