# Flutter creating list of widgets from a list of strings and getting errors

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to turn a list of strings into a list of widgets, which are generated in a previous widget dynamically through a text edit / text edit controller.

I've pulled the dynamic list `names` into a new stateful widget.

```
class NameMachine extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> names;

  NameMachine({Key key, @required this.names}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _NameMachineState(names);
  }
}

class _NameMachineState extends State<NameMachine> {
  final List<String> names;
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

I've then tried to create a list of widgets, but encounter issues with static members and initalisers.

```
final List<Widget> nameSlots = ...(names)
      .map(
        (names) => Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Text(
            names,
            textScaleFactor: 1.2,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
          width: double.infinity,
          height: double.infinity,
        ),
      )
      .toList();
```

Comment: Refer this solution for the dynamic string with widget https://stackoverflow.com/a/61248116/3946958

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter :- How to display dynamic widgets on screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61247539/flutter-how-to-display-dynamic-widgets-on-screen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

class NameMachine extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> names;

  NameMachine({Key key, @required this.names}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _NameMachineState();
}

class _NameMachineState extends State<NameMachine> {
 List<Widget> nameSlots;
 @override
 void initState(){
    super.initState();

    //the code below takes the argument passed to the constructor and 
    //map each item of the list to a Container widget and stores the result in nameSlots

    nameSlots = widget.names 
    .map(
    (names) => Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Text(
        names,
        textScaleFactor: 1.2,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
      width: double.infinity,
      height: double.infinity,
    ),
  )
  .toList();
 }
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        //some code
    }
}
```

What we do here is using the map method on the list not each item of the list (...(names) takes each item of the list) and map each item to a widget.

Comment: Your welcome. Please accept the answer so others can use it too! Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
class NameMachine extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> names;

  NameMachine({Key key, @required this.names}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _NameMachineState();
}

class _NameMachineState extends State<NameMachine> {
 List<Widget> names;
 @override
 void initState(){
    super.initState();
    names = widget.names
    .map(
    (names) => Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Text(
        names,
        textScaleFactor: 1.2,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
      width: double.infinity,
      height: double.infinity,
    ),
  )
  .toList();
 }
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

There might be some syntax errors in my but this might help you.